# Is it possible to serve a static html page at the root of a django project?

Tags: python, html, django, static, pythonanywhere

I have a django app hosted on pyhtonanywhere. The app resides at `username.pythonanywhere.com/MyApp`. I would like to serve a static html page at `username.pythonanywhere.com`. Is this possible? Essentially it would serve as an index linking to `/MyApp`, `/MyApp2`, and other future apps.

I can't seem to find any info on how to do this, but I assume I have to modify `mysite/mysite/urls.py` as navigating to root currently gives me a 404 with messages about failing to find a match in urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^/$', ???),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^MyApp/', indluce('MyApp.urls')).
]
```

The previous is my best guess (a bad one i know). That should (correct me if i'm wrong) match the root URL, but I have no idea how to say "hey django just look for a static file", or where that static html should live, or how to tell django where it lives.

Try not to cut my head off. I'm brand new to django.

P.S. I'm using django 1.8 in a virtualenv on PA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course you can. In cases where I just need to render a template, I use a [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/). Example:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='your_template.html'))
```

I usually order my URL patterns from *most* specific to *least* specific to avoid unexpected matches:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^MyApp/', include('MyApp.urls')),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='your_template.html')),
]
```

As far as where Django looks for templates, it's up to your configuration to tell Django where to look: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#configuration

Comment: and the html file lives in `mysite/mysite/templates/`?

Comment: It lives in wherever you have specified in the `DIRS` value in the config, which is a list of directory paths.

Comment: ah didn't see that last bit with the doc link. thank you sir!

Comment: I am not sure if this is a really _static_ file. Usually, static files are files that are server directly from the application server, for instance Apache, and not from the framework. Though I'm pretty sure the solution here was what OP wants, but not that it actually makes the file in question static.

Comment: @user4052054 I understand what you're saying, but it's also completely possible that the template file in the OP's question doesn't contain any Django template tags. At least that's the assumption I made when I answered this question.

Answer (score 3):

On PythonAnywhere, you can use the static files facility of your web app to serve the static file before it gets to Django:

Put a file called index.html in a directory and then point a static file entry to that directory. If the static file URL is / and the directory is the one with the html file in it, the file will be served at /.

Be aware that you don't want the directory to be above any of your code or you'll expose your code as static files i.e you don't want to use the directory /somewhere/blah if your code is in /somewhere/blah/code, you'll want to put it in /somewhere/no_code_here

Answer (score 0):

I have been tinkering with Django version 3.2, and I was able to serve a static HTML page at the root of the project after creating a Django app as in their official tutorial like the following in the root `urls.py` file:

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home/base.html')),
]
```

This is given that `home/base.html` is placed where the default template folder is. If I simply re-use the `polls` templates directory I can create a folder like `polls/templates/home/` to store `base.html`, for example.